# What does "spot basis" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "spot basis" mean, in the sentence "what you want to be able to do is develop the skill to go and do this on a spot basis"?

Answer (score 4):

It's similar to "spot" as in "spot price" - what would be paid for delivery of the goods "on the spot." So it means "to develop the skill to go and do this *without prior preparation*."

Comment: I deleted my answer as I think yours is better. I'll add it here for perhaps some additional insight: I would interpret this as meaning "as occasionally needed" or "ad hoc". Perhaps it also means "in very specific circumstances".

Comment: Interesting parallel from music: "sight reading."

Answer (score 3):

"spot basis" typically means on a one-time or ad-hoc basis. So, in the context of the sentence, it means to become competent enough at the task to be able to do it once.